# Tuning UDT's congestion control

Tags: udp, udp-data-transfer, congestion-control

I have an embedded device running Linux that serves sensor data across a LAN, but never WANs.  Occasionally it may reside on one end of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_fat_network.

The architecture I inherited uses TCP, but I'd like to add what amounts to real-time video over UDP.  I don't care about dropped packets or ordering. I only want to know on the client side when I've dropped, and on the server side if I'm sending too quickly.  I **never** want to retransmit.

Is there anywhere else I should look?  UDT is currently too slow given my initial benchmarks.  A naive UDP with-sequence-number client/server can sustain ~80 Mbit/s on this embedded system, whereas untuned UDT is running about 30 Mbit/s. If I use its SOCK_DGRAM interfaces, UDT appears to fall back too aggressively to the point at which it's usually running at 16 Mbit/s.  Has anyone successfully tuned UDT's CCC for this kind of an application? The highest throughput I've seen is 35 Mbit/s with UDT's sample applications.

Should I just skip ahead to RTP?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol

Comment: Cat, did you ever solve this problem.  I also use embedded Linux systems.  My systems use cell modems so we see very low TCP throughput.  I'm checking out UDT to see if that can improve the throughput.

Comment: I gave up and assumed that UDT was too CPU-intensive for the 400 MHz ARM XScale CPU. TCP throughput was fine, however!